# Facebook offline conversions without customer data

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I need to send offline conversions to facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions) but often I don't know the email or other user data. 
Is it possible to use data such as the Google Analytics client ID as an identifier?

I tried to send in the facebook pixel an additional field extern_id which is set to the analytics client id.

I send this identifier to Facebook with the offline API, unfortunately I don't find these conversions in facebook ads...

Comment: Under “Providing External IDs” it says there, _“There may be scenarios where you provide your own external ID to represent a customer and match them to someone on Facebook.”_ - so I guess unless you have a way to match the GA client ID to a specific Facebook user, I don’t think this makes sense to begin with.

Comment: Also explicitly says there (for cases where you provide match_keys and extern_id, or extern_id only: _“If no match is found, the unmatched data is not processed.”_ - which would match your observation of _“unfortunately I don't find these conversions in facebook ads...”_

Comment: Hi misorude, I'm trying to match the GA client ID to a specific Facebook user using the facebook pixel, for example:
fbq('init', '<?php echo ID_PIXEL_FACEBOOK;?>', {
                    extern_id:'xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx'});

xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx GA client ID.... Does not seem to work.

So without email is it impossible to send these events in your opinion?

I need to send transactions that take place after the user leaves the site.

Comment: _“I'm trying to match the GA client ID to a specific Facebook user”_ - how is that supposed to work, who should be able to make that connection? Facebook does not know which user is “associated” with any GA client ID …

Comment: GA client ID is an identifier chosen by me, I could generate a unique id per user.
I send this id to facebook when I launch the facebook pixel init with the parameter extern_id.

Comment: Okay, if you communicated such an external identifier to Facebook already while the user was active on your site, this should work. Show how exactly you send this value when uploading your offline conversation then.

Comment: Hi, this is my code https://gist.github.com/manu89ftt/e4a824590b1c84ec4ce637262a1a7dcc

Comment: It is not possible to do, it is necessary to send that identified in a list of customer to facebook, offline events for users not registered on facebook are impossible to manage.